# LongDayNames deprecated and returns wrong values

Tags: date, lazarus, dayofweek, weekday

I'm trying to make sense out of this on Lazarus Pascal

**Note:** `dtWeekEnding` is of type `TDateEdit`

```
ShowMessage( LongDayNames[DayOfTheWeek( dtWeekEnding.Date) ]);
```

My output expected is the *name of the day for a given value in dtWeekEnding*. But I have to issues:

1. I get a warning that **LongDayNames** is deprecated. Then what should I use?
2. The day name returned is incorrect. On the (drop down) calendar, it clearly shows the day but the message box is a day before it.

Am I missing something? Please advice.

Edit: For what it's worth, I tried this:

```
ShowMessage( LongDayNames[DayOfTheWeek( dtWeekEnding.Date) +1 ]); //Added 1 to the answer.
```

When I tried the above change, all days come out correctly BUT not Sunday. Sunday doesn't show at all. For example, selecting September 1st shows nothing as the name of the day.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In later Delphis these settings moved to a TFormatsettings record called "FormatSettings". FPC had such construct for years, and deprecated the old ones (just like recent Delphi versions).
2. This is dayofTHEweek() vs dayofweek() that have differing definitions of what the first day of the week is.

There was a note of this in the [dayofweek](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/dayofweek.html) help, but I now also added a reference from the help topic for short and [longdaynames](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/longdaynames.html) that will hopefully make this clearer (will be visible in the documentation of the next release)